# Best way to find inner node values using linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I have looks like the sample provided as below.
I need to find all the valuse under **Images** or **Image** node

```
<root>
  <Title>Press Relese 1</Title>
  <ReleaseDate>2014-07-24</ReleaseDate>
  <Description>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </Description>
  <Template>2</Template>
  <Images>
    <Image>
      <img src="/uploadedImages/MainSite/Content/PressReleases/300x340-slide01.png?n=3011" alt="slide01" title="slide01" />
    </Image>
  </Images>
  <Images>
    <Image>
      <img src="/uploadedImages/MainSite/Content/PressReleases/300x340-slide02.jpg?n=8663" alt="slide02" title="slide02" />
    </Image>
  </Images>
  <Images>
    <Image>
      <img src="/uploadedImages/MainSite/Content/PressReleases/300x340-slide02.jpg?n=6982" alt="slide02" title="slide02" />
    </Image>
  </Images>
  <Images>
    <Image>
      <img src="/uploadedImages/MainSite/Content/PressReleases/300x340-slide04.jpg?n=9958" alt="slide04" />
    </Image>
  </Images>
</root>
```

Can anyone suggest the best solution using linq?

This is the code what I have tried, but I am not getting the list of images, anything wrong with me?

```
var pressContentDetail = (from bdata in xmlDoc.Descendants("root")
                              select new
                              {
                                  Title = (string)bdata.Element("Title"),
                                  Description = (string)bdata.Element("Description"),
                                  Template = (string)bdata.Element("Template"),
                                  SlideImages = bdata.Descendants("Images")
                              }).ToList();
```

Comment: What do you get with this code?

Comment: am getting all other node values except Images

Comment: what is the type of 'SlideImages'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
var pressContentDetail = (from bdata in xmlDoc.Descendants("root")
                              select new
                              {
                                  Title = (string)bdata.Element("Title"),
                                  Description = (string)bdata.Element("Description"),
                                  Template = (string)bdata.Element("Template"),
                                  SlideImages = bdata.Descendants("Image").Elements().Select(x=>x.ToString())
                              }).ToList();
```

the value for `SlideImages`:

```
<img src="/uploadedImages/MainSite/Content/PressReleases/300x340-slide01.png?n=3011" alt="slide01" title="slide01" />

<img src="/uploadedImages/MainSite/Content/PressReleases/300x340-slide02.jpg?n=8663" alt="slide02" title="slide02" />

<img src="/uploadedImages/MainSite/Content/PressReleases/300x340-slide02.jpg?n=6982" alt="slide02" title="slide02" />

<img src="/uploadedImages/MainSite/Content/PressReleases/300x340-slide04.jpg?n=9958" alt="slide04" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Take SlideImages as string type. Then bind SlideImages data to Image control. Try this. I hope this will work.

```
var pressContentDetail = (from bdata in xmlDoc.Descendants("root")
                          select new
                          {
                              Title = (string)bdata.Element("Title"),
                              Description = (string)bdata.Element("Description"),
                              Template = (string)bdata.Element("Template"),
                              SlideImages = (string) bdata.Descendants("Images")
                          }).ToList();
```

Comment: Your code is exactly the same as the code in the question that does not work?

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit weird that you inside multiple `<Images>` elements have a single `<Image>` element that contains an `<img>` element but provided that this is the correct XML you can extract the `src` attribute of the images using this code:

```
var xDocument = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var pressContentDetail = new {
  Title = (String) xDocument.Root.Element("Title"),
  Description = (String) xDocument.Root.Element("Description"),
  Template = (Int32) xDocument.Root.Element("Template"),
  SlideImages = xDocument
    .Root
    .Elements("Images")
    .Select(x => (String) x.Element("Image").Element("img").Attribute("src"))
    .ToList()
};
```

To get the collection of `<Images>` elements I use `xDocument.Root.Elements("Images")`. For each of these elements I use `Select` to project the value of the `src` attribute by navigating down the XML hierarchy `(String) x.Element("Image").Element("img").Attribute("src")`.